# Python for loop get index and index+1

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function in python. The function is based on a algorithm. It is summation using sides of polygons with n sides. 
For each "loop" you add n[i]+n[1+i]. 
In python can you do this with for loops?
This is a very easy thing to do in languages like java and c++. But the nature of python for loops make it less obvious. Can for loops accomplish this or should while loops be use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and for-loop here:

```
>>> lis = range(10)
>>> [x+y for x, y in zip(lis, lis[1:])]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17]
```

If the list is huge then you can use [`itertools.izip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) and [`iter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter):

```
from itertools import izip, tee
it1, it2 = tee(lis)   #creates two iterators from the list(or any iterable)
next(it2)             #drop the first item
print [x+y for x, y in izip(it1, it2)]
#[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(N):  # i = 0,1, ... N-1
      val = n[i] + n[i+1]
```

if you want to 'wrap around', you can write

```
for i in range(N):  # i = 0,1, ... N-1
      val = n[i] + n[(i+1)%N]
```

.. or use the fact that n[-1] is the same as the last element

```
for i in range(N):  # i = 0,1, ... N-1
      val = n[i-1] + n[i]   # [N-1]+[0], [0]+[1], ... [N-2] + [N-1]
```

This approach will likely be slower but may be easier to follow than zips and iterations.